# How to create a custom 404 page handler with Play 2.0?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

What’s the preferred way to handle 404 errors with Play 2.0 and show a nice templated view?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can override the `onHandlerNotFound` method on your [`Global`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) object, e.g.:

```scala
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Result = {
    NotFound(views.html.notFound(request))
  }
}
```

Comment: did you create a page yourself? When I tried that code it's saying it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, this code assumes there is a `notFound.scala.html` template in your `views/` directory.

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy: Please be aware that **your solution works on 2.0.4 only**. In 2.0 it's onActionNotFound, see the differences:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaGlobal

Comment: Note that in Play 2.2.x the return type has changed so it should be wrapped in a Future.
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal

Answer (score 20):

Please note that there are really two different problems to solve:

1. Showing a custom 404 page when there is "no handler found", e.g. when the user goes to an invalid URL, and
2. Showing a custom 404 (NotFound) page as a valid outcome of an existing handler.

**I think the OP was referring to #2 but answers referred to #1.**

### "No Handler Found" Scenario

In the first scenario, for "no handler found" (i.e. invalid URL), the other answers have it right but to be more detailed, per the [Play 2.1 documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaGlobal) as:

Step 1: add a custom Global object:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader): Result = {
    NotFound(
      views.html.notFoundPage(request.path)
    )
  }   
}
```

Step 2: add the template. Here's mine:

```
@(path: String)

<html>
<body>
<h1>Uh-oh. That wasn't found.</h1>
<p>@path</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Step 3: tweak your conf/application.conf to refer to your new "Global". I put it in the controllers package but it doesn't have to be:

```
...
application.global=controllers.Global
```

Step 4: restart and go to an invalid URL.

### "Real Handler can't find object" Scenario

In the second scenario an existing handler wants to show a custom 404. For example, the user asked for object "1234" but no such object exists. The good news is that doing this is deceptively easy:

**Instead of Ok(), surround your response with NotFound()**

For example:

```
object FruitController extends Controller {

  def showFruit(uuidString: String) = Action {
    Fruits.find(uuidString) match {
      case Some(fruit) => Ok(views.html.showFruit(fruit))

      // NOTE THE USE OF "NotFound" BELOW!
      case None => NotFound(views.html.noSuchFruit(s"No such fruit: $uuidString"))
    }
  }
}
```

What I like about this is the clean separation of the status code (200 vs 404) from the HTML returned (showFruit vs noSuchFruit).

HTH
Andrew

Comment: You can skip your step 3 if you put your `Global` object in the root package, i.e. app/views/Global.scala instead of app/views/controllers/Global.scala like in your example. The default application.conf points there: `# application.global=Global`

Comment: In Play 2.2, the response must be wrapped in a Future: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do the same using Java instead of Scala you can do it in this way (this works for play framework 2.0.3):

Global.java:

```
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Results;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestHeader;


public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    @Override
    public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Results.notFound(views.html.error404.render());
    }
}
```

Asumming that your 404 error template is views.html.error404 (i.e. views/error404.scala.html).

Answer (score 3):

Please note that Play development team are making lots of efforts to move away from global state in Play, and hence `GlobalSettings` and the application Global object have been deprecated since version 2.4.

`HttpErrorHandler.onClientError` should be used instead of 
`GlobalSettings.onHandlerNotFound`. Basically create a class that inherits from `HttpErrorHandler`, and provide an implementation for `onClientError` method.

In order to find out type of error (404 in your case) you need to read status code, which is passed as a one of the method arguments e.g.

```
if(statusCode == play.mvc.Http.Status.NOT_FOUND) {
    // your code to handle 'page not found' situation 
    // e.g. return custom implementation of 404 page
}
```

In order to let Play know what handler to use, you can place your error handler in the root package or configure it in application.conf using `play.http.errorHandler` configuration key e.g.

```
play.http.errorHandler = "my.library.MyErrorHandler"
```

You can find more details on handling errors here: for [Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling) or [Java](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaErrorHandling).

Comment: typo: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling

Answer (score 2):

This works in 2.2.1.  In Global.java:

```
public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
    return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
        views.html.throw404.render()
    ));
}
```

Ensure that you have a view called `/views/throw404.scala.html`

Answer (score 0):

This works in 2.2.3 Play - Java

```
public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
    return Promise<SimpleResult>pure(Results.notFound(views.html.notFound404.render()));
}
```

html should be within /views/notFound404.scala.html
Dont forget to add Results.notFounf() and import play.mvc.Results;

Comment: Your question does not contain any information that is not already provided by at least one of the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, if you want to just redirect to main page, I solved it by this.

```
@Override
public Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
    return Promise.pure(redirect("/"));
}
```