# how to navigate to default page rather than default error page by Play,when the request for a particular page is not available

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In router file...

```
GET     /*file                       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

So I am accessing the pages in public folder as shown below

```
"192.168.2.7:9000/test.html"
```

**Problem:**

If the requested page is not existing (like `test22.html`)
then play showing the default error page.

But I want to navigate to default page like `index.html`,
when the request page is not existing.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of Play! you are using you can either override [`onActionNotFound`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) for `2.0` *or* [`onHandlerNotFound`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaGlobal) for `2.1` in the Global object.

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989444/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-handler-with-play-2-0) for guidance.

The links provided are for Scala but there are similar information for Java [here (2.0)](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal) and [here (2.1)](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGlobal)

Comment: thanks for replay.But it is not a solution for my problem.Let you see my reply and guide  me.