# Performing routes lookups within my Actions

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

What I'm trying to do is build out support for CORS in my Play 2.1 application.  The premiss is that anything that comes in on a path of /admin needs to get the CORS headers in the response.  This works well enough with cut-and-paste solutions I've cobbled together through StackOverflow.  Each of my Controller actions leverage a wrapped Action that shoves the CORS headers into the response.  The problem is my naive implementation now returns 200 OK on OPTIONS requests for URLs that don't exist in my routes file!  How do I modify my naive Controller to confirm that a URL exists in my routes file and 404 Not Found if I doesn't find a route?

conf/routes

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /hb                         controllers.Application.hb

# Admin API
POST    /admin/sessions             controllers.admin.Sessions.session
GET     /admin/apps                 controllers.admin.Apps.index
OPTIONS /admin/*url                 controllers.admin.Admin.options(url: String)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

My Admin Controller provides the common options handling

```
object Admin extends Controller {
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())

  def options(url: String) = CORS_Writer {
    Action {
      log.trace("options( url: {}", url);
      /*
       * I need to validate that url exists in the routes file here
       * (this doesn't compile, but conceptually is what I want).
       */
       if(routes(url)) { Ok } else { NotFound }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect

```
OPTIONS /admin/sessions HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

and

```
OPTIONS /admin/sessions HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

but

```
OPTIONS /admin/bob HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I'm new to both Scala and Play and I find the Play 2.1 documentation sorely lacking regarding the details of working with routes.  Please excuse me if this question seem rather simpleton.  I'm sure this is possible, I just don't know the incantation.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't common `onHandlerNotFound` good enough ?

- [How to create a custom 404 page handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989545/1066240)

You can make additional check to response with different error for paths starting with `/admin/`.

Comment: I don't think that will work due to my wildcarding all OPTIONS in the routes file (OPTIONS /admin/*url controllers.admin.Admin.options(url: String).  What I've done with this wildcard is made it so there is always a handler.