# Securing Pay Framework (2.1) routes file

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have been developing a play framework (2.1) java application but struggling to secure the routes file.

Is there actually a way to secure the routes file? so for example if a wrong request is typed in rather the the default: Action Not Found (These routes have been tried, in this order:) routes file being parsed and displayed is there anyway to change the response?

Thanks

Comment: do you want a custom 404 page? Something that acts as a fallback so people don't see your routes?

Comment: Actually i have found a solution: In my custom Global object i can override the onHandlerNotFound method to return a custom view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only happen when you run Play 2.x in DEV mode.

In production, you can override what to show by overriding onHandlerNotFound() in your Global method. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989444/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-handler-with-play-2-0) for more information about that.

Comment: Thanks Franz, i think we commented the same solution, around the same time