# Play Framework - define 404 page for assets

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using Play 2.3 (Java) framework and I want to set a 404 page.
I know about onHandlerNotFound method of GlobalSettings.

But assets seem to have their own handling - Assets class doesn't call my onHandlerNotFound method, only sends empty 404 status.

Can I somehow intercept errors in Assets and set my own handling?

It seems to me rather limiting that any asset that doesn't exist returns empty 404 page.

Thanks for any advice.

Edit: some code
From routes:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

From GlobalSettings:

```
@Override
public Promise<Result> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader arg0) {
   return Promise.<Result>pure(Results.notFound(
      errPage("notfound")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding *onHandlerNotFound* in the Global will not work here since a handler is found.

For the built in assets controller, when it cannot find a file it uses the onClientError of your project's HttpErrorHandler to get the result to display.

You can look at customizing it here:

Java: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaErrorHandling

Scala: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling

Here's a Scala example:

```
import play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent._
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
class ErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {

  def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
    Future.successful(
      // Your custom error page can go here.
      Status(statusCode)("A client error occurred: " + message)
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very similar question to the one asked in a different thread.

If you are using assets, I assume they are some objects like files? If so, you need to take a look at the second part of the solution from here:

[How to create a custom 404 page handler with Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989444/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-handler-with-play-2-0/18348112#18348112)

The one where Andrew E writes about "Real Handler can't find object" Scenario. That part is about a user requesting an object that simply does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the link talks about custom controller.
I need to intercept error handling of built-in Assets class.

I looked into its sources and it uses some errorHandler of type HttpErrorHandler, but since I only understand Java and not Scala, I don't understand how it's initialized and if it may be changed somehow.

Does anyone where can it be configured?

Comment: Could you post some code to understand better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have added some code snippets into the initial post.
But to specify what I want:

If someone goes at /sandkja, no route is choosen and GlobalSettings.onHandlerNotFound is called, and some error page is rendered.

But if someone goes at /assets/njdfhew, Assets controller handles the action, and it has its own error handling - in case of not found just an empty page with status 404.

I want to somehow inject an errorHandler into the Assets class, so that I could customize error messages for not found urls in assets directory.